# Struts exclude pattern with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, struts2

I did a lot of homework before coming here to the experts , appreciate any pointers on my question

I need to run a merged (not integrated) app that was basically combined version of struts2 and Spring and some base servlets. Was able to get the combined war file up without errors in tomcat. My intention is to based on url patterns route to appropriate framework (a well beaten problem :)

Let's call the single context as myctx

My situation:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And with

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/myctx/springurl1/.*?"/>
```

If I leave the url pattern as `/*` in the filter mapping, all the original struts2 actions are accessible but nothing is accessible from spring related

If I make the struts filter url-pattern as `/myctx/.*?`, noting is accessible from original struts component but spring url is accessible.

Appreciate any pointers here

If it matters using struts 2.3.16 and spring 3

Are there any other ways ? On springframework less url patterns to enumerate

Thanks a bunch in advance

-CJ

Comment: Some code missing from my original post
 <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/myctx/springurl1/.*?"/> in struts.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use spring servlet separately from Struts 2 framework you should use the configuration settings in your `struts.xml` to exclude servlet from filter mapping.

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/myctx/?.*"/>
```

The servlet mapping in `web.xml` ([The DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)):

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myctx/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman for answering.  Definitely it helps. however, 'have the following: a) /myctx/struts_actions should be handled by struts2 b) /myctx/spring_rqsts should be handled springservlet and rest c) /myctx/rest_srvlts should be handled by base servlets with those mappings. In this situation, how would the excludePattern work? --sorry 'tried and am trying all combinations, still getting not the result.. I can enumerate all url patterns as needed (spring and base servlets are few, and hence looking to enumerate in exclude pattern) any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: cant believe 'struggled on this because of a malformed jar in the lib that included an old struts.xml that happily took precedence over the main struts.xml which 'was editing and rerunning to debug. Once the malformed lib is corrected, things fell in place :) Thanks again  Roman.